# appending only first object

Tags: python, list, dictionary

guys idk why my dict appending only first item from list,and i dont have any ideas for that

```
class Nums:

    def __init__(self, lst_nums: list, dict_nums: dict):
        self.lst = lst_nums
        self.dict_nums = dict_nums
        self.dict_nums = {}

    def changer(self):

        self.dict_nums = {"": ""}
        for i in self.lst:
            if i in self.lst:
                self.dict_nums = {i: i}
            return self.dict_nums


f = Nums(lst_nums=[1, 4, 5, 6, 7], dict_nums={})

with open('number.txt', 'w') as number:
    number.write(json.dumps(str(f.changer())))
```

Comment: `self.dict_nums = {i: i}` creates a new dict.  Instead do self.dict[i] = i.  Please take care to post a [mre]  Your code relies on a numbers.txt so we cannot run your code.  In generally you want to _minimize_ your example to make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `__init__()` you initialize an empty dict (good) with `self.dict_nums = {}` but in `change()` you then overwrite it (twice).  You probably want to just modify it like this instead:

```
    def changer(self):
        for i in self.lst:
             self.dict_nums[i] = i
        return self.dict_nums
```

Comment: @makim thanks is implied, upvote the answers that are helpful when you can, and accept the best answer so we know you are all set.

Comment: can i write u in telegram or something?

Comment: @makim no, just add comments here.

Answer (score 1):

To start when you return the `return self.dict_nums` you are not letting the for loop process in its entirety.

Second, itering your list twice will not be helpful here unless you are attempting to multiply or add the numbers together or something.

```
class Nums:

def __init__(self, lst_nums: list, dict_nums: dict):
    self.lst = lst_nums
    self.dict_nums = dict_nums
    self.dict_nums = {}

def changer(self):
    for i in self.lst:
        self.dict_nums[i] = i
    return self.dict_nums


f = Nums(lst_nums=[1, 4, 5, 6, 7], dict_nums={})

with open('number.txt', 'w') as number:
    number.write(json.dumps(str(f.changer())))
```

Which produces

```
"{1: 1, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out in the comments `self.dict_nums = {i: i}` creates a new dictionary with a single key/value pair. Not only that, but you're returning after the first execution of the loop. The `if` statement is also redundant since every element will be in the list(since you're looping over the list)

```
def changer(self):

    self.dict_nums = {"": ""}
    for i in self.lst:
        self.dict_nums[i] = i
    return self.dict_nums
```